# Convergence of series with logarithms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a question. Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ be a convergent series of positive real numbers. Determine if the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\log a_n$$ converges or diverges.

I think the latter series converges, and the explanation is analyzing the behavior of the function $f(x)=x\log x$ when $x\to 0^+$, but I cannot get the conclusion.

Comment: What if $a_n = 1/[n\log^2(n+1)]?$

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes no.

Comment: @zhw. my writing speed was just faster then my brain.. ;)